# How to change lua_number from double to float properly in Lua 5.2.3

Tags: c++, lua

I want that lua_number gets a float instead of a double. I know that I have to change something in luaconf.h but I dont know what. I am using Lua 5.2.3 and Visual Studio C++.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, one reason is to reduce memory used by Lua values.

Answer (score 11):

You need to edit `luaconf.h` and change these:

- `LUA_NUMBER` to `float`
- `LUA_NUMBER_SCAN` to `"%f"`
- `LUA_NUMBER_FMT` to `"%.7g"`
- `l_mathop(x)` to `(x##f)`
- `lua_str2number` to use `strtof`

For the last two, you probably need a C compiler that supports (some of) the C99 standard.

Comment: When I change `LUA_NUMBER_SCAN` to `"%.7g”`, Visual Studio says: `error C2001: new line in constant`.

Comment: What about this? `#define LUA_NUMBER_DOUBLE`

Answer (score 2):

In luaconf.h

```
/*
** {==================================================================
@@ LUA_NUMBER is the type of numbers in Lua.
** CHANGE the following definitions only if you want to build Lua
** with a number type different from double. You may also need to
** change lua_number2int & lua_number2integer.
** ===================================================================
*/

#define LUA_NUMBER_DOUBLE
#define LUA_NUMBER  double
```

This is actually the Lua 5.1 luaconf, but the 5.2 conf should be similar.

Comment: There is more to be changed.